# Saving contour plot graphics in eps format

Tags: plotting, export

I want to save my contour plot graphics in eps format, but when I try, the points plotted using `Epilog` do not show in the eps version. The plot looks like this in my Mathematica notebook:

[image]

But the saved eps looks like this:

[image]

None of the ploted points are visible. I have tried grouping but it doesn't work.

Comment: Which version of Mathematica do you use? How do you save: with Right Click -> Save Grahic As.. or with Export command? I don't have your code, so tried with simple example from Help: `ContourPlot[{Abs[Sin[x] Sin[y]] == 0.5,  Abs[Cos[x] Cos[y]] == 0.5}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, Epilog -> {Green, PointSize[0.05], Point[{0, 1}]}]`.  Both methods work for me.

Comment: To come up with an answer, most of us would want to run tests with your code. But you give us no code. I think you  are unlikely to get an answer unless you edit your question to include ***all** the code needed to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Without having any code of yours, I could imagine that a prior export as *.pdf could help, which is imported in a 2nd step again and then you export it as *.eps file.

```
Export["Folder\\2ndExport.eps",Import[Export["Folder\\1stExport.pdf", YourContourPlot,  ImageSize-> {N[GoldenRatio] 550, 550}, ImageResolution -> 600]],ImageResolution -> 600];
```

Comment: Why do you use `ImageResolution`? It makes rasterization, which is not needed with OP's example plot consisting of lines and points, no shades, no gradients etc. And what is the reason of using PDF? In my understanding (and in my example in comment below question) simple `Export["file.eps",plot,"EPS"]` is enough to produce nice vector pisture.